# Anchor inside Ajax tabs with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, tabs, anchor

I am building a FAQ page and I want to load the content inside a page page via Ajax with jQuery tabs.

I want to avoid to have different pages for every FAQ so I want to load the content with an anchor. How can I do this?

The following code does not work:

```
<li>
    <a id="faq-sei" href="faq1.html#sei" title="display">Accedo alle offerte online </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the link

```
<pre><code><li ><a id="faq-sei" href="faq1.html#sei" title="display">Accedo alle offerte online </a></li></code></pre>
```